# Terraform - Iterate through map of maps depending on value of internal map

Tags: for-loop, foreach, resources, terraform

i'm trying to create a resource depending on a value of the internal map of a map.
If that specific value is true then create the resource

Please find below the code:

```
variable "ip_restrictions" {
  type        = map(map(string))
  default = {
    test01 = {
      name                      = "test01"
      start_ip_address          = "0.0.0.0"
      end_ip_address            = "0.0.0.0"
      is_firewall               = false
    },
    test02 = {
      name                      = "test02"
      start_ip_address          = "0.0.0.0"
      end_ip_address            = "0.0.0.0"
      is_firewall               = true
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "sql_firewall_rules" {
  for_each = {
    for restr in var.ip_restrictions :
    restr => restr
    if restr.is_firewall == true
  }
  
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.sqls.name
  start_ip_address    = each.value.start_ip_address
  end_ip_address      = each.value.end_ip_address
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct form of your `for_each` should be:

```
  for_each = {
    for key, restr in var.ip_restrictions :
      key => restr if restr.is_firewall == "true"
  }
```

This will filter out all records with `is_firewall` of `false`.

Comment: Is the newline somehow impacting the functionalities of the for?

What i'm also trying to understand is if the "key" you've added before => is the key of the map i'm trying to iterate through ({test01 = {valuesOfTheObject/map}, test02 = {valuesOfTheObject/map}}) or the key of the object itself {name ="",start_ip_address="",etc...}\

Comment: @RMDev No, you can have it in second line. I just put it as it saves some space.

Comment: I've edited the question, could you please go through the question again?

Comment: @RMDev I don't see any change in the question?

Comment: There you go :)
What i'm also trying to understand is if the "key" you've added before => is the key of the map i'm trying to iterate through ({test01 = {valuesOfTheObject/map}, test02 = {valuesOfTheObject/map}}) or the key of the object itself {name ="",start_ip_address="",etc...}

Comment: The  the `key` will be  `test01` and `test02`. The `restr` will be `valuesOfTheObject/map`.

Answer (score 3):

Since your `var.ip_restrictions` is a **map** and not a **list**, you need to iterate over it like a map (returning a key and value). The shortest possible way in your situation:

```
for_each = {
  for key, restr in var.ip_restrictions :
    key => restr if restr.is_firewall
}
```

Gives:

```
"test02" = {
  "end_ip_address"   = "0.0.0.0"
  "is_firewall"      = "true"
  "name"             = "test02"
  "start_ip_address" = "0.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: is "key => restr if restr.is_firewall" going to work also if i don't have a boolean? Because i've created the object as map of maps of string.

Comment: Yes, I tested this in terraform 0.13.3 with the same map you used. Even with the is_firewall set as "true" or "false" the outcome is the same.

Comment: key => restr, this part means that it should return a new map with "test02" as key and the other elements as value.